# Laravel 5 modal form data not updating

Tags: php, laravel, modal-dialog, save

My route:

```
Route::post('/edit/{id}',['as'=>'edit','uses'=>'datacontroller@update']);
```

My controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $task = veriler::findOrFail($id);
    $input = $request->all();

    $task->fill($input)->save();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

My modal form page:

[image]

Only the last data updating. I could not solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $task = veriler::findOrFail($id);
    $input = $request->all();

    $task->fill($input);
    $task->save();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Fill function takes the input, and save function saves to the databaes.

Comment: You should clarify exactly what you changed.